# execute javascript on postback if specfic server control is pressed

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, asp.net

I don't really know javascript. I am using the following code to create a popup on a button click for some in line ASP.NET server controls/HTML:

```
<script src="http://ajax.microsoft.com/ajax/jquery/jquery-1.3.2.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="http://ajax.microsoft.com/ajax/beta/0911/Start.debug.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="http://ajax.microsoft.com/ajax/beta/0911/extended/ExtendedControls.debug.js"
    type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    Sys.debug = true;
    var popup;
    Sys.require(Sys.components.popup, function () {
        popup = Sys.create.popup("#popup", {
            parentElementID: "target",
            onShow: '{AnimationName: "Sequence", AnimationChildren: [{AnimationName:"HideAction", visible: true},{AnimationName:"FadeIn"}]}'
        });
    });
```

This button opens the content and it works great:

```
<input type="button" onclick="popup.show()" value="Search Stories" />
```

My issue is that two of the server controls make the box disappear on postback. The postback is necessary for one of them for sure. This makes sense to me because the page is refreshing and the button hasn't been pressed. How can I make it where under a certain circumstances (one of these 2 actions that causes postback to occur) The page postbacks with the popup showing?

Comment: You could use an `UpdatePanel` so the page doesn't actually refresh, you could use ajax to post the data instead of doing a postback, or you could use `RegisterStartupScript` to call `popup.show()` after the postback so the popup reappears after the page reloads.

Comment: could you show me the specific RegisterStartupScript call for this particular javascript?

Answer (score 0):

You could try this:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z9h4dk8y.aspx

```
ClientScriptManager cs = Page.ClientScript;

if (!cs.IsStartupScriptRegistered(this.GetType(), "ShowPopup"))
{
  String cstext1 = "alert('Hello World');";
  cs.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "ShowPopup", "popup.Show()", true);
}
```